# pandas read .txt doc with specific seperator

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to read a .txt file using pandas that has a `^` type separator.

I keep running into error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 7: invalid start byte`

tried to use `pd.read_csv(txt.file , sep = '^' , header = None)`

`txt.file` has no headers ,

Am I missing an argument?

UPDATE:

`13065^000000000^aaaaa^test , conditions^123455^^01.01.01:Date^^^^^^ 77502^000000123^aaaaa^test, conditions^123456^^^^^^^^`

seems there is is uneven amount of the `sep ^` on each row.

How could I fix?

Comment: I created a small txt file with ^ separator and read it successfully with your read_csv code. So the issue is not about the ^ sperator. You certainly have an invalid character in your txt file which is causing the error (as explained by the error message).

Comment: ok, thanks. If some of the data is seperated with multiple `^^^` will that cause error?

Comment: is the encoding of the file correct? if its a windows generated file it might be cp252

Comment: @JamesCook It is allowed to have nothing between 2 separators (missing values will give NaN values). The only thing mandatory is to have the same number of separators on every rows.

Comment: The problem is probably on the encoding, since the error says that pandas couldn't decode a byte from your data. You can either share a sample of your data or try different encodings [listed here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)